# Meaning of "Wir waren uns all die Jahre näher"

Tags: meaning

> Dirk untersucht, inwiefern die Bundesrepublik durch die Wiedervereinigung verändert worden ist. Nicht nur der Osten wurde westlicher, auch der Westen wurde östlicher. "Wir waren uns all die Jahre näher, als wir wahrhaben wollten."

What is the meaning of

> Wir waren uns all die Jahre näher, als wir wahrhaben wollten.

?

Is it "We were nearer to each other during these years than we wanted to admit"? Does "Wir waren uns näher" mean that we were near each other, and "all die Jahre" refers to the years after the Wiedervereinigung?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

very close – part 1 is correct, part 2 not 100%:

"Wir waren uns näher" actually means "We were **nearer** (or 'closer') to each other" –  – and this kind of asks for "***als***" ('than').

so I would translate it as this:

> "All these years we were closer (to each other), than we wanted to admit"